# Add text to textarea using class name

Tags: javascript

When the user clicks a tag, I want to add append text to textarea using class name.

Click event handler works,but not adding text to the textarea.

Here's the code I have so far.

```
var boardName;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-open-card-composer').click(function() {
         boardName = document.title.replace(' | Trello', '');
         $('.list-card-composer-textarea').text += boardName;

    });
});
```

And, Here's the text area

```
<textarea class="list-card-composer-textarea js-card-title" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; height: 36px;"></textarea>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've tested it with alert function, and it works fine as alert message pops up with boardName. However, when I try to add the boardname into a textarea, it doesn't add the text.

Comment: Why should it? `text` is a property of `option` and `script` elements. In jQuery, as jrath has answered, there's `text` method though. It useful to do some research before asking, especially reading [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/) of the used library would help.

Comment: Yeah, but text function seems not to work for me.

Comment: How would we know about that, you haven't used `text` function in your example...?

Comment: I've tried jrath's way. Didn't work.

Comment: [No?](http://jsfiddle.net/6vuLuaq1/). You implement it correctly, and it works ...

Comment: As I know, it should work. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please re-read my previous comment. A tip:Just don't blindly copy-paste some code, fit it to your own structure and variable names.

Comment: I did. I did some tests. And, it actually changes other texts, but only doesn't work for textarea.

Comment: Does the fiddle I've linked above work in your browser? Have you checked the console for errors? Also, `textarea` is actually a form element, it has a value, text content or htm are optional, not necessary implemented in all platforms.

Comment: Yes, the fiddle works fine in my browser, and in console, there's no error showing.

Comment: Basically, when the user clicks the a tag, then textarea shows up. I think we need to add the text into textarea after the textarea shows up. But, what we're doing is adding text to textarea, which is hidden and then textarea will show up. So, is there any way to change the order of event handlers to be executed?

Comment: Can't answer that, since there's nothing about hidden elements in your example. Anyway, whether the textarea is hidden or not doesn't change anything. You can add content to hidden elements as well. Perhaps you should post the code you really have.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery text() is function so instead of

```
$('.list-card-composer-textarea').text += boardName;
```

use

```
var data = $('.list-card-composer-textarea').text();
$('.list-card-composer-textarea').text( data + boardName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use html instead of text

```js
var boardName;

    $('.js-open-card-composer').click(function() {
         boardName = 'test';
         var data = $('.list-card-composer-textarea').html();
         $('.list-card-composer-textarea').html(data+boardName);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="list-card-composer-textarea js-card-title" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; height: 36px;"></textarea>

<div class="js-open-card-composer" style="width:20px;height:20px;border:1px solid red"></div>
```